# How to initialise an Ada Unbounded String from GetEnv & Literal

Tags: string, ada, getenv

G'day, I'm finding compile errors on what ought to be a simple piece of code.  the objective is to use an environment variable as part of a default value.  We are using Ada95, so I wondered if it's a version thing.

The '*model*' we stated with looks (something) like this:

```ada
  Default_Override_Message_Text   : Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String
      := Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_Unbounded_String(
             Gnat.Os_Lib.Getenv( "DATA_FILES" ) & 
             "/override_required.txt" );
```

I'm getting an error on the **&**:

- `invalid operand types for operator & invalid operand types for operator "&"`

Whereas, this is fine.

```ada
  Default_Override_Message_Text   : Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String
      := Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_Unbounded_String(
             "DATA_FILES" & "/override_required.txt" );
```

I turned to the internet and books, is just seems that it should work and here's a difficulty with typing or something.  The example given on PLEAC give me an error too.

- [Establishing a default value](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_ada/strings.html#AEN20)
- [GetEnv example](http://www.adapower.com/index.php?Command=Class&ClassID=GNAT&CID=243)
- Look at "GetEnv()" on: [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.pegasoft.ca/resources/boblap/16.html)

```ada
    username : string := Gnat.Os_Lib.Getenv("USER");
    DATA_FILES  : String := Gnat.Os_Lib.Getenv( "DATA_FILES" );
```

Gives the error:

- Builder results expected type "Standard.String" **181:37** expected type "Standard.String" Builder results
- Builder results found type "System.Strings.String_Access" **181:37**

I thought with that approach I can

```ada
DATA_FILES   : String := Gnat.Os_Lib.Getenv( "GPS_DATA_FILES" );

Default_Override_Message_Text : Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String
        := Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_Unbounded_String(
                DATA_FILES & "/override_required.txt" ); -- ERROR

DATA_FILES_2 : String := "GPS_DATA_FILES";        -- WORKS

Default_Override_Message_Text : Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String
        := Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_Unbounded_String(
                DATA_FILES_2 & "/override_required.txt" ); -- WORKS
```

I'm still doing something wrong with the GetEnv because it looks like everything we want will happen similar to the `DATA_FILES_2` option would work (according to my compiler) if I can correctly assign the value from GetEnv().

Can someone point out my error?  Or is Ada95 using different rules to the examples I'm looking at?

Comment: Ada 2005 added packages `Ada.Directories` and `Ada.Environment_Variables` so that you can do what you need without hard-coding OS-dependent file name conventions or relying on GNAT packages.  Perhaps it's time to consider upgrading?

Comment: @ajb ... thanks.  Yes I see now.  Fortunately our friend Keith below has set me straight.  Many thanks, I'm just getting up to speed on this language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration of the `Gnat.Os_Lib.Getenv` function is:

```
function Getenv (Name : String) return String_Access;
```

Note that it returns a String_Access, not a String (I'm not sure why).

Adding a `.all` to get the `String` value from the `String_Access` result should fix your problem:

```
Default_Override_Message_Text   : Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String
   := Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_Unbounded_String(
         Gnat.Os_Lib.Getenv( "DATA_FILES" ).all & 
         "/override_required.txt" );
```

(Having `Gnat.Os_Lib.Getenv` return a `String_Access` rather than a `String` could have been an opportunity to distinguish between a missing environment variable and one whose value is the empty string. Unfortunately, it returns an access to an empty string in both cases.)

Comment: Thanks Keith -- so it looks like those examples are mistaken?